# Convert RGB to Grayscale in ImageMagick (but not the entire image)

Tags: imagemagick

I have the following bar chart:

[image]

I transformed it to greyscale using the following command:

```
convert image.tif -set colorspace Gray -separate -average image_greyscale.tif
```

and my result was

[image]

It is greyscale indeed, but the axes and the legend are grey as well. This is obvious now, but I'd like them to be black, like in the original image. Something like this:

[image]

How can I do it? Remake the bar charts again, with a greyscale palette, is not possible right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the plum colour and change that to gray20 and then select the lime colour and change it to gray80 like this:

```
magick chart.png -fuzz 10%               \
   -fill gray20 -opaque "rgb(68,1,84)"   \
   -fill gray80 -opaque "rgb(122,209,81)"  result.png
```

[image]

Or, as a one-liner:

```
    magick chart.png -fuzz 10% -fill gray20 -opaque "rgb(68,1,84)" -fill gray80 -opaque "rgb(122,209,81)"  result.png
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want to do in ImageMagick is simpler than your command. Just do

Input:

[image]

```
convert barchart.png -colorspace gray result.png
```

Result:

[image]